# humburber menu isnt display on web

Tags: html, css, web, sass

I want to make humburger menu and write this code

```
<header class="header">
<nav class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
<a href="/" class="header__logo">
<img src="images/logo.svg" alt="easybank" />
</a>
<a href="#" class="header__menu">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

and then this code in scss

```
.header{

nav{
    padding: 24px;
    
}

&__logo{
    img{

    }
}
&__menu{ //humburgermenu
    > span{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 4px;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: $darkBlue;

        &:not(:last-child){
            margin-bottom: 5px;

        }
    }

}}
```

the humbuger menu doesn't display when I go back to the website and when I inspect it, it shown that span 0x17. What should I do? thank you so much

Comment: Suggestion : add a language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

> You have not closed some tags

```css
.header nav {
     padding: 24px;
}
 .header__menu > span {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 4px;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: #aaa;
}
 .header__menu > span:not(:last-child) {
     margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
<nav class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
<a href="/" class="header__logo">
<img src="images/logo.svg" alt="easybank" />
</a>
<a href="#" class="header__menu">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</a>
</nav>
```